# How to change text color when click item of RecylerView in android

Tags: android, colors

This is Adapter!

```
public class CategoryAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CategoryAdapter.CategoryAdapterObjectHolder> {
private static String LOG_TAG = "CategoryAdapter";
private List<Category> mCategory;
private static MyClickListener myClickListener;

public static class CategoryAdapterObjectHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
    TextView mTextTitle;

    public CategoryAdapterObjectHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        mTextTitle = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_menu);
        DebugTool.logD(LOG_TAG + "Adding Listener");
        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        myClickListener.onItemClick(getPosition(), v);
    }
}

public void setOnItemClickListener(MyClickListener myClickListener) {
    this.myClickListener = myClickListener;

}

public CategoryAdapter(List<Category> myHistoryData) {
    mCategory = myHistoryData;
}


@Override
public CategoryAdapter.CategoryAdapterObjectHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.item_menu, parent, false);
    CategoryAdapterObjectHolder dataObjectHolder = new CategoryAdapterObjectHolder(view);
    return dataObjectHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(CategoryAdapter.CategoryAdapterObjectHolder holder, int position) {

    holder.mTextTitle.setText(mCategory.get(position).getName());


}

public void addItem(Category dataObj, int index) {
    mCategory.add(dataObj);
    notifyItemInserted(index);
}

public void deleteItem(int index) {
    mCategory.remove(index);
    notifyItemRemoved(index);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mCategory.size();
}


public interface MyClickListener {
    public void onItemClick(int position, View v);
  }
}
```

This is OnItemClick

```
  @Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    ((CategoryAdapter) adapter).setOnItemClickListener(
            new CategoryAdapter.MyClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(int position, View v) {
                    TextView mTextItem = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.text_menu);
               //     mTextItem.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.color_text_white));
                    if (position == 0) {
                       Utils.showToast(getContext(), "POSITION 0");
                    } else if (position == 1) {
                        Utils.showToast(getContext(), "POSITION 1");
                    } else if (position == 2) {

                        Utils.showToast(getContext(), "POSITION 2");
                    } else if (position == 3) {

                        Utils.showToast(getContext(), "POSITION 3");
                    } 
                }
            });
}
```

My item it have colour white.

I want when :

I click at position == 0.

Text Color item of position == 0  change to dark. and position different have colour white.

I click position == 1 :

Text colour item of position == 1 change to colour dark. And position different back colour white.

I click position == 2 :

Text colour of position == 2 change to Dark and position different back colour white.

I click position == 3 :

Text colour of position == 3 change to Dark and position different back colour white.

Please. Help me!

Answer (score 2):

1- Create variable **currentPosition** default = **-1** in **adapter**

```
private int currentPosition =-1;
```

2- **onBindViewHolder** set default text color **Black** and when user click view:

- notifyItemChanged(currentPosition)  - update default view for old view(reload)
- Set text color **White**.

---

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final DataObjectHolder holder, final int position) {
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = holder.view.getLayoutParams();
        holder.view.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        final String text = mDataSet.get(position);
        holder.textView.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        holder.textView.setText(text);
        holder.view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(currentPosition>=0) {
                    notifyItemChanged(currentPosition);
                }
                holder.textView.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                currentPosition=position;
            }
        });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand fully what you are trying to achieve but if you are trying to change the colour of your `TextField`'s text and assuming your `OnItemClickListener` is being called:

Create a field that will hold all of your `TextView`s.

```
private TextView[] textViews;
```

In your `onCreateView` method.

```
textViews = new TextView[4];
textViews[0] = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textViewOne);
textViews[1] = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textViewTwo);
textViews[2] = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textViewThree);
textViews[3] = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textViewFour);
```

Now in your `OnItemClickListener`

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    ((CategoryAdapter) adapter).setOnItemClickListener(
            new CategoryAdapter.MyClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(int position, View v) {
                    Color white = getResources().getColor( R.color.color_text_white );
                    Color dark = getResources().getColor( R.color.color_text_dark );
                    for ( int i = 0; i < textViews.length; i++ ) {
                         TextView textView = textViews[i];
                         if ( i == position ) 
                             textView.setTextColor( dark );
                         else 
                             textView.setTextColor( white );
                    }
                }
            });
}
```

Comment: I think. you are misinterpreting my question

Comment: So do you have 4 different text fields that you want to change the colour of when a position is clicked?

Comment: I'm sorry I really do not understand what you are asking then

Answer (score 0):

```
class ColorAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ColorSizeViewHolder> {
Context context;
ArrayList<ColorContents> colorContents;
int current_position=-1;
int previous_position=-1;
public ColorAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<ColorContents> colorContents) {
    this.context = context;
    this.colorContents = colorContents;
}


@NonNull
@Override
public ColorSizeViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v= LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.color_size_model,parent,false);
    return new ColorSizeViewHolder(v);

}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ColorSizeViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    holder.color_size.setText(colorContents.get(position).getColor());
    holder.color_size.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent));
    holder.color_size.setTag(position);

    holder.color_size.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int pos = (int)v.getTag();


            holder.color_size.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));

            current_position=pos;
            if (previous_position!=-1 && current_position!=previous_position)
            {
                notifyItemChanged(previous_position);
            }

            previous_position=pos;


        }
    });

holder.setItemClickListner(new ItemClickListner() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(int pos) {

    }
});

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return colorContents.size();
}
```

}

Comment: Coud you please add some explanation how this solution solves the problem?

Comment: when click so color change and condition specify that when you click again so color not remove previous position use to reset default color and current position use for check condition if we click again on same position so text color will maintain due to false condition if click on any other position so color change